# "undefined" instead of ID in URL on transition in Ember and Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a pretty standard post model with a title and a text field. I have two routes for the model -- new route and show route. I want to create a post from new route and then transition to show route.

This is my router file

```
this.route('post-new', { path: '/posts/new' });
this.route('post-show', { path: '/posts/:postId' });
```

and `submit` action in `post-new` controller is something like this.

```
actions: {
  submit() {
    const { title, text } = this.getProperties('title', 'text');
    let post = this.store.createRecord('post', {
      title: title,
      text: text
    });
    post.save().then(() => {
      //success
      this.transitionToRoute('post-show', post);
    }, () => {
      //error
    });
  }
}
```

So I am expecting this to redirect from `http://localhost:4200/posts/new` to something like `http://localhost:4200/posts/23` (assuming `23` is id).
The `save()` is successful and record is created on the backend (which is rails) and I also see the `post` record updated in browser (it now has an ID) using Ember Inspector. But the redirection is happening to `http://localhost:4200/posts/undefined`.

How can I make this to redirect to something like `http://localhost:4200/posts/23` after save ?

Btw, The versions are:
ember cli : 2.3.0-beta.1
ember : 2.3.0
ember data : 2.3.3

---

**UPDATE**

I was able to make it work by replacing this

```
this.transitionToRoute('post-show', post);
```

with this

```
this.transitionToRoute('/posts/' + post.id);
```

But I am hoping for a solution using the route name and not actual route path.

Comment: Why don't you try: `this.transitionToRoute('post-show', post.id);`

Comment: Asfaik dynamic segments are underscored `:post_id`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
post.save().then(savedPost => {
  //success
  this.transitionToRoute('post-show', savedPost);
},
```

Comment: `post.save().then((savedPost) => {
  this.transitionToRoute('post-show', savedPost);
});`
I tried this. Doesn't work.

Comment: Still transitions to undefined? What about `savedPost.get('id')` instead of `savedPost` as second method argument?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `serialize` hook on your route.

```
serialize(model) {
  return { postId: model.get('id') };
}
```

This will allow you to avoid calling the model hook if you already have the model.  So, both of these will work as expected:

```
this.transitionToRoute('post-show', post);    // this will NOT call model() hook
this.transitionToRoute('post-show', post.id); // this will call the model() hook
```

More information available in the [API docs for Route](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize).